# Suse Linux, slowing down system time to in sync with time server

Tags: linux, date, time, suse

Normally is the time of a Linux server (due to ntpd) in sync with the time server.
However the ntpd is running but server is now running 20 seconds ahead.
How do I slowdown the server little by little. So I can correct the server time almost the same as time server, before restart ntp daemon.
Because when I restart de ntpd the server instantly fix time. That’s not I want.

On HP-UX you have command:  “date –a sss.fff”  works perfect (on HP-UX) but is not available on linux.

Regards  Paul.

Answer (score 0):

remove the `-x` from `/etc/sysconfig/ntp`, if it is there.  So that:

```
NTPD_OPTIONS="-x -g -u ntp:ntp"
```

becomes:

```
NTPD_OPTIONS="-g -u ntp:ntp"
```

Change the following to no in the same file:

```
NTPD_FORCE_SYNC_ON_STARTUP="yes"
```

also set as **first** parameter in `/etc/ntp.conf`

```
tinker panic 0
```

stop your ntp.

```
echo 0 > /var/lib/ntp/drift/ntp.drift
```

start your ntp.